# how to add string at the start and end of each line for pascal output

Tags: string, pascal

Making school projects in pascal i want to add some ascii art pascal uses write,writeln for output i want a tool to paste my string at it and add to my string write or writeln syntax for string at the start and ond of each line
for instance

```
●▬▬▬▬๑۩۩๑▬▬▬▬▬●
My Program
●▬▬▬▬๑۩۩๑▬▬▬▬▬●
```

should look like this

```
writeln('●▬▬▬▬๑۩۩๑▬▬▬▬▬●');
writeln('My Program');
writeln('●▬▬▬▬๑۩۩๑▬▬▬▬▬●');
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want the ascii art to be a variable string, put in by the user?

Comment: Write it yourself. Its a good exercise.

Comment: *Making school projects in pascal*, you should be writing this tool yourself, or at least making a reasonable effort to do so. We're not in the business of recommending tools or anything else, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It's hard to get what you want. Downvoted. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): it explains you how to write a good Q on S.O. You just can't come here and tell _I want this_ without any draft and expect to get an answer (even if some kind people might give one).

Comment: First of all it's the first Post that i'm posting on this site so i'm sorry if i missuse something or i made my question unclear.All ive asked is that i'm making school projects in pascal and i want to add some ascii art to my programs to make them more pleasing to the eye and i have to paste the huge string of charachers of ascii to notepad and manually add the write(' at the beggining of each line and '); at the end of it so the computer can undeastand it's string i wanted something to automate that process for me i'm on a really basic level the only language i know is pascal at the moment

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you're using an inferior editor. If you weren't using Notepad, you might have access to a macro interpreter. I use Vim, for example, where I'd accomplish the task this this: Press `qq` to begin recording a macro. Type `Iwriteln('`, <esc>, `A');`, <esc> to insert the text, `j` to go down one line, and `q` again to stop recording. Then I'd type `@q` as many times as necessary to transform all the pasted text into Pascal code. If the source text contained any apostrophes, I'd fix them by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to define your own procedure which 'does the output' rather than using 'writeln'. Something like this:

```
Procedure MyOutput (const s: string);
begin
 writeln (fancytext);
 writeln (s);
 writeln (fancytext)
end;
```

where 'fancytext' is your ASCII art string (defined as a constant).